# SyntaxException in python method. Unsure why

Tags: python

Can anyone explain why I get the following syntax error when running the `setup.py install`:

**Exception**

```
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cardstream/payment.py', 46, 15, '            for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()\n'))
```

**Code**

```
 @classmethod
 def decode(this, query):

      """Decode a request/response from the given query string.
      """

      return {
          key: value if len(value) > 1 else value[0]
              for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()
      }
```

The line it refers to is the `for`. I'm familiar with Python, but not so much that I can figure out why it's moaning.

**Edit** For completeness, here is the exception when the script is run manually:

```
[...pythonsdk]$ python test/test_gateway.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test_gateway.py", line 4, in <module>
    from REMOVED.payment import Gateway
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/REMOVED-0.0.1-py2.6.egg/REMOVED/payment.py", line 46
    for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Old Python version without dictionary comprehensions?

Comment: Oh, maybe. Running on a box that probably hasn't been updated for some time. I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: That was it. Thank you @KlausD.

Comment: Yes, from those paths it looks like you have Python 2.6.  Dictionary comprehensions were added in 2.7.

Comment: Unfortunately the live box only has 2.6, but I was able to confirm this was the case by installing 2.7.x on a windows box and running. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the dict comprehension to the equivalent `dict()` constructor call:

```
return dict((
          (key, value if len(value) > 1 else value[0])
              for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like you splitting your dictionary comprehension on separate lines.

Just put it on a single line:

```
return {
    key: value if len(value) > 1 else value[0] for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()
}
```

or if you absolutely have to split use line continuation character `\`

```
return {
    key: value if len(value) > 1 else value[0] \
        for key, value in parse_qs(query).items()
}
```

Comment: This has been solved by using Python 2.7.x rather than the 2.6.6 version on the live box. But thanks for your time :)